# Dojo equivalent of the following jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, dojo

I am working on a project that I wanted to use jquery for, however it's come to light that it is mandatory to write in **dojo**, I've never worked with it before and am having some trouble reading up online as to how to use it.

Below is the code I was using:

```
<script>
        window.onload = function() {
            getManager($("#team_name").val());  
        }
        
        function getManager(team) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "getManager.php",
                data: {team:team}
            }).done(function( manager ) {
                $("#manager_name").val(manager);
            });
        }
</script>
```

Essentially, there is a drop down `<selection>` field, when selected (and upon window loading) it should prefill the **read-only**  box below it based upon which team is listed. See the below screenshot for a better idea:

[image: screenshot]

I the above code works fine with jquery, I can't seem to find the equivalent for **dojo**.

This is the html for the **selection** field:

`<select name="team" id="team_name" onchange="getManager(this.value)" type="text" readonly>`

and this is the html code for **text input field**:

`<input name="manager_name" id="manager_name" type="text" readonly/>`

The code **must be written in dojo** as the rest of the page does, unless there is a way to override the dojo with jquery?

Comment: What's your dojo version?

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = function() {
    getManager(document.getElementById('team_name').value);  
}

function getManager(team) {
    require(["dojo/_base/xhr"], function(xhr){
        xhr.post({
            url:"getManager.php",
            timeout: 4000,
            content: { team:team },
            load: function( manager ){
                document.getElementById("#manager_name").value = manager;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: perhaps I'm doing it wrong, but the above code doesn't appear to be doing it's intended purpose :/

Comment: the following code snippet works for this selection field, I think my code should be following that sort of standard?

` <script>
 dojo.addOnLoad( function() {
     dojo.connect(dojo.byId('team_name'), "onchange", function(evt) {
      alert("changed!");
      });
  });
 </script>`

Comment: Most of that code is just plain JS and works everywhere, but I'm a little unsure when it comes to the ajax function, I've done something like above before and got it working, but I rarely use Dojo. Check the DOCS for more ways to do ajax -> http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/quickstart/ajax.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dojo 1.7 and above no need to use window.onload() or even dojo.addOnLoad() - I think this is what you are looking for

```
require(['dojo/dom', 'dojo/domReady!', function(dom) {
  getManager(dom.byId('team_name').value); 
});


function getManager(team) {
  require(['dojo/request/xhr', 'dojo/dom'], function(xhr, dom) {
    xhr.post('getManager.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      data: {team: team}
    }).then(function(manager) {
        dom.byId('manager_name').value = manager;
    }, function(error) {
        console.error('couldn\'t fetch manger!');
    });
  });
}
```

[domReady!](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/domReady.html) - is an AMD loaded plugin that will wait until the DOM has finished loading before returning